# Seller API of flipkart to access the list of Product CakePHP

Tags: flipkart-api

I want to access API https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/listing-api-docs/LMAPIRef.html of this WEBSITE I have already generated token but latter I want Access its LIST of products which I upload on flipkart

Flipkart API documents given billow URL

Example 1 - Create Listing

Success: HTTP code 2xx
Seller API of flipkart to access the list of Product using this link
Request: https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/SKUID/listings

```
{
    "skuId": "SKUID",
    "fsn": "FSN",
    "attributeValues": {
        "mrp": "2400",
        "selling_price": "2300",
        "listing_status": "INACTIVE",
        "fulfilled_by": "seller",
        "national_shipping_charge": "20",
        "zonal_shipping_charge": "20",
        "local_shipping_charge": "20",
        "procurement_sla": "3",
        "stock_count": "23"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "response": {
        "skuId": "SKUID",
        "listingId": "LISTINGID",
        "status": "created",
        "errors": []
    }
}
```

Comment: you seem to have forgotten to a) try anything b) explain what the question is

Comment: sir, actually i want to access API of Flipkart which is E-commerce website of INDIA and To understand my question you will have to open of this link  https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/listing-api-docs/LMAPIRef.html#postlisting-label

Answer (score 6):

`$url  = "https://api.flipkart.net/oauth-service/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Seller_Api";
    $curl = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "app_id:app_secret");
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $tokan = json_decode($result,true);
    $url  = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/orders/search";
    $curl = curl_init(); 
    $json = '{
              "filter": {
                "orderDate": {
                  "fromDate": "2016-01-01T19:00:00Z",
                  "toDate": "2016-03-28T19:00:00Z"
                }
              }
            }';
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:Bearer '.$tokan['access_token'],
    ''
    ));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $ee = curl_getinfo($curl);
    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($ee);
    curl_close($curl);
    print_r($result);`

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. But please can you post how can I retrieve shipment detail. Right now, I am trying https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/orders/shipments?orderItemsIds={orderitemid}. But getting error [code] => INVALID_ITEM_IDS.

Comment: Hi @Manohar Can you please help me how to generate access token to flipkart api